# Google account access (mail calendar) with Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, oauth

I'm completely new to Android development and would like to find out if the following is at all possible, and the best way to approach it:

- User logs into Google account - NOT stored on the phone (OAuth??)
- App displays their GMail emails - does not need to send, only receive/read
- App can access their calendar and display events - again read only

That's all for the Google side of things! I've only ever used Facebook auth - so am unsure as to how Google works. I can't seem to find any definitive answers on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a web application that uses OAuth to log onto google. 
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth

then you can use GMail API's to use the OAuth token to access user's email
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview

then for calendar you have the Google Calendar API's also accessed using OAuth.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

You can create a web app and use your android app to access your web server database via API's you create. Using this data you provide a nice GUI for your android users and provide user interactions.

Another method would be to use only the android client without a web app as mentioned by Jan Gerlinger.

You can also check out the source code for k-9 mail app for ideas here:
https://github.com/k9mail/k-9

It's a full-featured, open source android email client that supports many protocols including IMAP, SMTP and Microsoft Exchange accounts too. You can dig through the source code to find out how they do it.

Comment: There's absolutely no need here to have an own web server between the client and Google, this can all be done directly from the client.

Comment: Yes there isn't an absolute need. I was just providing an option. I've upvoted your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is all possible.

- Use [Google Play services](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/09/google-play-services-and-oauth-identity.html) to get an OAuth 2 *access token* for the Google APIs. For GMail IMAP and read-only Calendar API access you will need to state these scopes:

  ```
  https://mail.google.com/
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
  ```
- Use some IMAP library for Android using your OAuth 2 *access token* (e.g. [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html), check out [this Android JavaMail tutorial](https://namheo.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/smtps-imaps-in-java-android/) and Google's sample for [using OAuth2 with JavaMail](https://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode)).
- See the [Calendar API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) for how to access the user's calendar.

Comment: The first link says that if the email requested doesn't exist on the device then it'll throw a GoogleAuthException and this is fatal. If this is the case, then the user will have to register the account on the device which is something Andy doesn't want. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that. You can then still switch to doing the OAuth dance manually using the [Installed applications flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) and a web view.